# UNION ALL & UINION

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying  to use this Operator,
firstly : do all my table fields name has to be same ?
eg :

```
**Table A** 
Source| Ranking|Number|Product|City|Customer Name

**Table B**
source_1|Ranking_1|number|product_1|city_1|Customer Name_1

select *
 from Table A
where Number IS Null
Union All
Table B
```

please provide me if the query is correct, i sit necessary to have same fields name and structure to use this operator ?

Comment: What happens when you run this query?

Answer (score 1):

`UNION (ALL)` works by combining the results of two (or more) queries (not *tables*). It requires that the queries being unioned return the same number of columns, with the same datatype in each column.

Column names do not really matter. The names defined in the first query are used as references.

It looks like your datastructures do satisfy this requirement, so:

```
select
    source,
    ranking,
    number,
    product,
    city,
    customer_name
from table_a
union all 
select
    source_1,
    ranking_1,
    number,
    product_1,
    city_1,
    customer_name_1
from table_a
```

Note: `union all` just combines the resultsets. `union` eliminates the duplicates across the resultset, if any (his means more work for your database, so don't use it unless you do *mean* to avoid duplicates).